# Django, exclude parameters from request.GET

Tags: django, url, parameters, request

What's the best way to exclude parameters from request.GET?

eg, given a url param `?a=a&b=b&c=c` and I want to take out param b to generate url param to `?a=a&c=c` without changing `request.GET`

Right now I am looping through the keys to take out b

```
params = {}
for key,value in request.GET.items():
  if not key == 'b':
    params[key] = value

url = urllib.urlencode(params)
```

I am wondering if there is a better, more elegant way to achieve the same result? eg.

```
request.GET.urlencode(exclude=['b',])
```

or even this, better

```
urllib.urlencode(request.GET.exclude('b'...)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should work:

```
get = request.GET.copy()
del get['b']

params = urllib.urlencode(get)
```

Comment: nice I thought about using this approach too, but then I need to wrap that around with try and catch blocks due to uncontrollable params.

Comment: If you want to avoid try/catch use my approach like so:               x = cp.pop('b', None) and then check: if x is not None: ...

Comment: This doesn't work if you got multiple get parameters of the same name. for instance ?a=1&a=2&b=3&c=4

Comment: This is great! At the last line get.urlencode()  would be enough

Answer (score 2):

You cannot manipulate the `request.GET` directly because it is an immutable `QueryDict`.
So make a shallow copy and then remove the desired key.

```
cp = request.GET.copy()
cp.pop('b')

params = urllib.urlencode(cp)
```

Answer (score 1):

All these answers almost got it right, but failed for the edge case where there are multiple parameters with the same key name, which is valid (and the whole reason why django uses a `QueryDict` and not a `dict`). If you use urllib's `urlencode` it will lose the extra parameters, you need to use the urlencode provided by `QueryDict`.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict

> QueryDict is a dictionary-like class customized to deal with multiple
>   values for the same key. This is necessary because some HTML form
>   elements, notably `<select multiple="multiple">`, pass multiple values
>   for the same key.

So the correct way is:

```
querydict = request.GET.copy()
if 'b' in querydict:
    del querydict['b']
return querydict.urlencode()
```